# could not load library plpython3.dll

Tags: plpython, postgresql-10, postgres-plpython

I am getting an error while creating an extension in Postgresql version 10

> could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
```

**Note:** Using Postgresql 10 on Window 10

Comment: downloaded language package for python, perl and tcl , but same problem existing

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210979/postgresql-unable-to-create-plpythonu-extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have struggled a lot with this. For me only worked when I installed the **right version** of python and added paths to environment variables.

Try version python-3.4.0.amd64 for windows 64bit or other versions from this [Python 3.4.0 downloads Link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/)

Environment variables to add:

- C:\Python34\Scripts
- C:\Python34\

Comment: where to find this information ? like for plpython3u which python version is required ?

Comment: > Where to find this information ? Like for plpython3u which python
> version is required ? Answer: C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/[version]/doc/installation-notes.html

Comment: for PostgreSQL 13 it is Python 3.7

Comment: The Postgres installation notes may be wrong. Such as for Postgres ver.15. Python3.10 NOT 3.9 is required. Use dependency walker as per this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001890/installing-plpythonu-on-windows