# how to install python3 in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

I'm trying to work with plpython in postgresql
So I run the command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u
```

but I get the error:

```
Erro SQL [58P01]: ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/lib/plpython3.dll": unknown error 126
```

I read some solutions like this:
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907232/could-not-load-library-plpython3-dll)

but none of them helped me.
I checked if the DLL exists in the postgres directory, and it is present in the directory

I'm using Windows 11, I have the latest version of Python installed on my computer, and also the environment variables are installed correctly, what could be causing this error?
I'm using dbeaver

**Edit 1**

I followed a Languge package installation toturial from this link:
[EDB Docs](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/language_pack/latest/installing/windows/)

I also installed the correct version of Python as described in this postgresql document:

```
C:/ProgramFiles/PostgreSQL/15/doc/installation-notes.html
```

I added a system/user environment variable called PYTHONHOME% with the path:

```
C:\edb\languagepack\v3\Python-3.10
```

but I still get the same error as above.

I also added all the python environment variables (when installing python it already gives the option to install automatically)

Comment: 1) Where did you install Postgres from?  2) In order for `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u` to work the supporting language files  needed to be installed. Best guess is you have not installed them.

Comment: I installed postgres from edb, this site:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

@AdrianKlaver

Comment: Then from here [EDB Download](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) you need to click on [EDB PostgreSQL Language Pack Guide](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/language_pack/latest/) and follow the instructions.

Comment: I did what you suggested, I also reinstalled my postgresql, but I still get the error proposed above
@AdrianKlaver

Comment: 1) Did you do the steps here *Configuring Language Pack with PostgreSQL on Windows* from [Windows Install](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/language_pack/latest/installing/windows/). 2) Are you running Postgres in a virtual env or container?

Comment: I'm running it from my localhost, and I followed it from windows install
I also read a document that is located at:
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\doc\installation-notes to see the correct version of python to be installed (3.9), but I still haven't gotten any results
@AdrianKlaver