# Tried everything. plpython3.dll just refuses to work. "The specified module could not be found"

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I've gone through 6 questions on Stack Overflow on this topic (can't find them all now to link them all) Nothing worked. I had python 3.12 installed and I installed the edb language pack to get the right version of python.

I've added every single thing there is to add to Path and other system variables.

Then I uninstalled python 3.12 and deleted the language pack and deleted the environment variable clutter that I added to get just one fresh install of python 3.11. I added all the paths to Path as suggested by the answer of this question

[could not load library plpython3.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907232/could-not-load-library-plpython3-dll)

Looking through dependency walker on plpython3.dll I see this.
[image]

I'm not exactly tech savvy but I assume PYTHON311.DLL being showed without question mark means that plpython3.dll sees it right?

Then what is going wrong?